# Editor de fotografías

Tags: android

Estoy haciendo un app en Android, que al tomar una foto la guarde en una resolución predefinida, por ejemplo 300X400, el problema es que no logro configurar la cámara para poder realizar dicha función, alguna idea de como lo puedo hacer?

Estoy utilizando la cámara nativa de Android y este es el código que uso para llamar a la cámara:

```
  private void openCamera() {
         try {
             File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), MEDIA_DIRECTORY);
             boolean isDirectoryCreated = file.exists();
             if (!isDirectoryCreated)
                 isDirectoryCreated = file.mkdirs();
             if (isDirectoryCreated) {
                 Long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 10000;
                imageName = timestamp.toString() + ".jpg";
                 mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + MEDIA_DIRECTORY
                         + File.separator + imageName;
                 File newFile = new File(mPath);
                 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                 intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(newFile));
                 startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_CODE);
             }
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si realizas un  `startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_CODE)` dentro de `onActivityResult()` al obtener la imagen puedes realizar el cambio de tamaño:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    //Obtiene el bundle.   
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    //Obtiene la imagen.
    Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

    //Crea imagen escalada 300 x 400.
    imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap , 300, 400, false);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, bytes);

    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + File.separator + "myimagen.jpg");
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
    fo.close();

}
```

Comment: Gracias por el código, me funciono muy bien.

Comment: Hola Jaron, me da mucho gusto, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con un Intent como este:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputX", 300);
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputY", 400);
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getTempUri());
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat",
                        Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

Comment: Gracias por el código, pero este recorta la imagen, yo necesito que la reduzca de tamaño no que la recorte, ósea que mantenga todas sus características solo que mas pequeña.